# postman: "Could not get any response" when passing laravel passport token

Tags: laravel, api, postman, laravel-passport

I am working with a laravel api, it strictly deals with ajax requests.
After successful login, the client will receive a laravel passport token for sequential requests.

The api has this route which simply return the authenticated user's details:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::post('/user/details', 'API\UserController@details');
});


// in UserController...
public function details() {
  $user = Auth::user();
  return response()->json([
    'user' => $user
  ], 201);
}
```

When i use postman to test my api, i get this response if i adding:

{Accept: application/json, Authorization: "Bearer " + LARAVEL_PASSPORT_TOKEN}

to the request header:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjQrI.png)

but if i only have {Accept: application/json} in the header.
It will give me back a normal Json unauthenticated response.

So, it would be great if someone knows what is going on and give me some insight about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, i m sure it's running. it gives me back response if i remove the token from the request header

Comment: where is employees route? which you calling you have only defined details route of user which is a post request

Comment: it should be     Route::get('/user/details', 'API\UserController@details');
and in postman http:\\siteurl\api\user\details

Comment: still not working if i change the request type. And the image i use is redirected from other post. So it's not correctly representing my path. But i am the url i m using i correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you follow your routes like

```
Route::get('/login','ApiController@accessToken');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth:api']], function()

{

   Route::post('/todo/','ApiController@store');

   Route::get('/todo/','ApiController@index');

   Route::get('/todo/{todo}','ApiController@show');

   Route::put('/todo/{todo}','ApiController@update');

   Route::delete('/todo/{todo}','ApiController@destroy');

});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {

   return $request->user();

});
```

And for more information visit article : [Create A REST API in Laravel With Authentication Using Passport](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/rest-api-laravel-passport-authentication/)

Comment: right i was following this article: https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876